# Shouldn't there be a "follow" option on profile page of users?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Sorry if I had given a wrong suggestion! But I think that Physics Stack Exchange is also a Q/A social media platform, so it would help us to trust the answers of the highly followed users. The follow option may also increase healthy competition between users but it would definitely be a healthy one. Is the suggestion fine?

Comment: A little searching, especially on the mother meta, will find numerous discussions where the community consensus is that SE is *not* a social network and that features which would be nice for social-networking reasons have intentionally not been implemented. The user RSS feeds explained in the linked posts are nice, though.

Comment: Related: *[Is Stack Overflow a social networking site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261)* (über meta). See also [questions linked to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/65261).